# How to Order by enum in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, enums, sql-order-by

I want to order by a string column where that column is an enumeration. For example:

```
+----+--------+----------------------+
| ID |  NAME  |        STATUS        |
+----+--------+----------------------+
|  1 | Serdar | ACTIVE               |
|  2 | John   | DEACTIVE             |
|  3 | Jerry  | WAITING_FOR_APPROVAL |
|  4 | Jessie | REJECTED             |
+----+--------+----------------------+
```

I want to order by `STATUS`. It should sort the results such that the first result must have STATUS = WAITING_FOR_APPROVAL, then ACTIVE, then DEACTIVE and then REJECTED.

Is there any way to do that in SQL? Is there something like Comparator in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enumerate the values in a `CASE` statement and order by that

```
SELECT id, name, status
  FROM your_table
 ORDER BY (CASE status 
                WHEN 'WAITING_FOR_APPROVAL' THEN 1
                WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 2
                WHEN 'DEACTIVE' THEN 3
                WHEN 'REJECTED' THEN 4
                ELSE 5
            END)
```

Comment: can I implement this with Hibernate criterias?